# How can I verify a socket listener?

Tags: c#, wcf, sockets, wireshark

I have created an application which starts a listener (it is a WCF application). 
After I run the application, is it possible to verify whether listener is running correctly, and port it is listening to using a networking tool like wireshark,etc?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use e.g. netstat, in a console type:

```
netstat -an
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is to try to use another listener on the same port. You'll get a bind exception.

Answer (score 0):

use http://porttest.blogspot.com/ to verify that connection open